# Programs and tool to scan open source software for vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, open-source, vulnerabilities

Since my business uses a lot of open source software I was wondering if there was a way to scan for vulnerabilities in the code before we either compile it, ./configure, make etc...

Or as scripting languages for either web servies for to run on bash, sh, perl etc.

Are there some good tools, programs out there to use for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes whitesource (now mend) has a solution for that:
https://www.mend.io/open-source-security/